# Spring Boot RestTemplate exchange 400 bad request

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, spring-boot

I have a problem with Spring Boot RestTemplate exchange.

I have the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/add")
public @ResponseBody String addFromTo () {
    String apikey = "";
    String baseurl = "http://demowebshop.webshop8.dk/admin/WEBAPI/v2/orders?start=2018-10-05T20%3A49%3A41.745Z&end=2018-10-15T20%3A49%3A41.745Z&api_key=" + apikey;

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setBasicAuth("", apikey);

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(" ", headers);
    ResponseEntity<OrderResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(baseurl, HttpMethod.GET, request, OrderResponse.class);

    return "Some text.";
}
```

What I want is the equivalent of:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic {encodedapikey}' 'http://demowebshop.webshop8.dk/admin/WEBAPI/v2/orders?start=2018-10-06T06%3A43%3A40.926Z&end=2018-10-16T06%3A43%3A40.926Z&api_key={apikey}'
```

I've tried using Postman with the exact same URL, and adding Basic Auth with the apikey, and an 'Accept: application/json' header, and that works fine, but when I run this code, I get the error message:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
400 Bad Request
```

**EDIT:**
Pastebin link to the exception thrown by the program:
https://pastebin.com/jdYJ2nv7

Comment: is `setBasicAuth` should be `'' "` ?

Comment: There should be no username. It also works in browser if you try to access the URL, it asks for username and password, and I leave the username blank and use the apikey as password.

Comment: It seems something missing ..if u see code String apikey = ""; but where are you setting this string value ..it is always pass as "''.

Comment: The apikey field is not normally missing, I just didn't include it in the question.

Comment: As u said in previous comment " and I leave the username blank and use the apikey as password" .have u configure ur webapplication with this setting & also type=Internal Server Error, status=500). there are many cause of this erro see the logs and update your question with exact exception/error trace.

Comment: I added a pastebin link to the exceptions thrown.

Comment: You aren't posting the same... The parameters are encoded again leading to `%3A` being encoded again to something else. Next to that you aren't providing the `encodedapikey` as you do with CURL. So you aren't doing the same but expect the same result...

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you're saying, but when I debug and look at the headers sent to the restTemplate.exchange() method, they are exactly the same as in Postman.

Comment: It isn't only the headers the URL is also re-encoded so leading to `%3A` being encoded itself. Leading to invalid results I would ay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your curl request you are using an `apikey` and `encodedapikey`. Whereas in your Java code you don't. Next to that you are also passing an encoded URL as the URL to use. This will result in encoding the encoded URL again. So don't do that. Instead use a URL with placeholders and supply values for them.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/add")
public @ResponseBody String addFromTo () {

    String apikey = "";
    String baseurl = "http://demowebshop.webshop8.dk/admin/WEBAPI/v2/orders?start={start}&end={end}&api_key={apikey}";

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("start", "2018-10-05T20:49:41.745Z");
    parameters.put("end", "2018-10-16T06:43:40.926Z");
    parameters.put("apikey", apikey);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setBasicAuth("", apikey);

    ResponseEntity<OrderResponse> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(baseurl, OrderResponse.class, parameters);

    return "Some text.";
}
```

The code above uses a proper parameterized URL together with a map containing values for the placeholders. Notice that those aren't encoded, as that will be handled by Spring!. Finally you can simply use the `getForEntity` method to get the result instead of the `exchange` method.

A final suggestion, Spring Boot already configures a `RestTemplate` which you can (re)use. You don't need to create a `RestTemplate` each time you need one (it is quite a heavy object to create, and after creation it is thread safe so it is enough to have a single instance).

```
public YourClassCOnstructor(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    this.restTemplate = builder.basicAuthorization("", apikey).build();
}
```

Ofcourse you can also put this in an `@Bean` method and inject the specific `RestTemplate` into your class.

Comment: Great answer, but if I use getForEntity instead of exchange, how do I include the headers?

Comment: I suggest using the `RestTemplateBuilder` to create the `RestTemplate` (once!) and set the authentication in there instead of each time in the method. That way you don't need to set the headers.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpHeaders.setBasicAuth(String, String)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#setBasicAuth-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is used for username and password only, not for basic token.
If you want to use basic token try something like headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + apiKey) instead of headers.setBasicAuth(...)